# How to insert/update native queries in DB using spring JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

Am working on a Spring boot application using spring data JPA.  The DB is a legacy one.  There is a **staging** table which contains  *insert/update queries* as CLOB data.

I have written a pojo for the **staging** table. The pojo implements CRUDRepository interface. I fetched the records from list() method and iterate the CLOB data. The queries present in the CLOB needs to be executed in other DB. The queries are insert/update queries related to 20+ tables.

Without creating pojos for that 20+ tables,  how can I execute those SQL's.
The SQL's need no modifications, just need to execute the same that I fetch from the staging table. Is
 `EntityManager.createNativeQuery("insert/update")`

a possible solution, or is there a better approach to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with JPA native queries for sure. Or even with plain JDBC.

But I recommend having a look at jOOQ. jOOQ generates POJOs for accessing and modifying the data and has a DSL that leads to compile time checked data access:

https://www.jooq.org/

jOOQ is free for OpenSource databases like MySQL, PostgreSQL etc. and affordable for commercial ones like Oracle.